# Micro-assembly language how to do loop arithmetic shift right

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, microcoding, mic-1

```
ixor1   MAR = SP = SP - 1; rd       // takes next to word on stack 
ixor2   OPC = TOS                  // OPC is number of bits to shift       2
ixor3   H = MDR                    // H is the number to be shifted       5
// What i need to do is arithmetic shift right value in H by TOS 
// for example if my TOS stored in opc is 2 and H = 5 I am trying to do 5 >> 2 
// however the architecture only allows arithmetic shift right >> by 1 . I was thinking of just looping 
// H = H >> 1   5 times or OPC no. of times how would I implement that ?
ixor4   H = H >> 1
ixor5   MDR = TOS = H; wr; goto Main1  // sets MDR AND TOS as H and goes back to Main code
```

What i need to do is arithmetic shift right value in H by TOS. for example if my TOS stored in opc is 2 and H = 5 I am trying to do 5 >> 2
however the architecture only allows arithmetic shift right >> by 1 . I was thinking of just looping
H = H >> 1   5 times or OPC no. of times how would I implement that ?

Comment: I've tried to edit your code to improve clarity, but you're mixing code and comment so it's not always clear to me which is which.

Comment: If the architecture only lets you shift by 1, then you'll have to shift by 1 multiple times in a row. Which CPU is this?